# Get the iteration number inside a MATLAB for loop

Tags: matlab

Say I have a for loop in MATLAB:

```
scales = 5:5:95;
for scale = scales
    do stuff
end
```

How can I get the iteration number inside a MATLAB for loop as concisely as possible?

In Python for example I would use:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(scales):
```

where idx is the iteration number.

I know that in MATLAB (like in any other language) I could create a count variable:

```
scales = 5:5:95;
scale_count = 0;
for scale = scales
    scale_count = scale_count + 1;
    do stuff
end
```

I could otherwise use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
scales = 5:5:95;
for scale = scales
    scale_count = find(scales == scale);
    do stuff
end
```

But I'm curious to know whether there exists a more concise way to do it, e.g. like in the Python example.

Comment: What do you mean by loop count? Wouldn't that just be `scale`? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I meant the iteration number. E.g. scale == 5 at iteration number 1; scale == 10 at iteration number 2; etc.

Comment: Ah. I think the best way is just to declare a variable then; AFAIK there isn't a cleaner way of doing that.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the following:

```
scales = 5:5:95;
for iter = 1:length(scales)
    scale=scales(iter); % "iter" is the iteration number.
    do stuff
end
```

Comment: Yes right thanks, that's another usual solution, but still not more concise :(

Answer (score 2):

Since `for` iterates over the columns of whatever you give it, another way of approximating multiple loop variables would be to use an appropriately constructed matrix:

```
for scale=[5:5:95; 1:19]
    % do stuff with scale(1) or scale(2) as appropriate
end
```

(my personal preference is to loop over the indices as per Parag's answer and just refer to `data(index)` directly within the loop, without an intermediate. Matlab's syntax isn't very concise at the best of times - you just get used to it)

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB way is probably doing it with vectors.

For example suppose you want to find in a vector if there is a value that is equal to its position. You would generally do this:

```
a = [10 20 1 3 5];
found = 0;
for index = 1:length(a)
    if a(index) == index
        found = 1;
        break;
    end
end
```

Instead you can do:

```
found = any(a == 1:length(a));
```

In general

```
for i=1:length(a)
    dostuff(a(i), i);
end
```

can be replaced with:

```
dostuff(a(i), 1:length(a))
```

it dostuff can be vectorized or

```
arrayfun(@dostuff, a, 1:length(a))
```

otherwise.

Comment: Of course you can replace 1:length(a) with your own range, e.g. 5:5:95 or whatever